# Javascript function inside Object Methods: When should you (and shouldn't) include return inside a function? Sample code below

Tags: javascript, function, object, return, this

I have an object.
Inside that object is a function property *calcBMI()* that creates another property inside that object *(this.bmi)*.
Inside the function, *the first solution has return* and the *second solution doesn't*.
when you call out the function, both solutions create a new property, nonetheless. Why is it so? And when can we opt not to include *return* inside a function?

**First solution:**

```
var mark = {
    fullName: 'Mark Miller',
    mass: 78,
    height: 1.69,
    calcBMI: function() {
        this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
        **return this.bmi**;
    }
}
mark.calcBMI();
```

**Second solution**

```
var mark = {
  firstName: "Mark Miller",
  mass: 78,
  height: 1.69,
  calcBMI: function () {
    this.bmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
  },
};
mark.calcBMI();
```

Comment: It depends on the scenario right? When you want to use the value of bmi somewhere else you can return it . When you just want to initialize something , you can choose to not return it

Comment: FYI: "function property inside an object" is, usually, called a "method".

Comment: I'd recommend, as I understand, to use `return`.  
Using `this.bmi=...` creates a property.  If you don't want that, just `return ...calculation...` - even without using `bmi`, say: `return this.mass / (this.height * this.height);`

Comment: Also, you can change the "object" to a "class", say `Person`, with constructor that takes `name, mass, height`.  (`weight` instead of `mass`?).  Then you'd use: `mark=new Person("Mark Miller", 78, 1.69)`, `console.log(mark.calcBMI())`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that a function property of an object is called a method. I'm just starting to learn the fundamentals of JS so I still keep forgetting these little things. Appreciate the suggestion iAmOren and your suggestions make sense. I also realized that including return is in general good practice.

Thanks also Harmandeep, I understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

Although the **return** statement of a JavaScript **Function** is not *mandatory* - A good coding practice is for all functions to return some value in their point of exit.
That value can be simply *true* or *false*.

Anyhow, a function execution will return a value by default, even if there is no literal declaration of *return* statement anywhere in the function body. The function will return ***undefined***.

But for good coding practice and better debugging premise the return should always be utilized by at least returning **true** for process execution success or **false** if it isn't. No matter if it's being used as a sole method on some object property, or a complete program closure platform.

Even a simple built-in command such as ***delete*** [something] will return ***true*** or ***false*** signaling you about a success or a failure on your aimed action. Because with that return you can continue to the next level or branch out to a new or different attempt of completing the same task.

---

**The Third** (my preferred) **solution**

Between your first and the second version, I think the third is more practical; has a better usability and less confusion :: the idea is to completely discard the calcBMI method and go straight to the freshly `[object].bmi` calculated value! Live...

```js
var mark = {
    fullName: 'Mark Miller',
    mass: 78,
    height: 1.69,
    get bmi(){ return this.mass / (this.height * this.height) }
}
;
console.log( mark.bmi );
```